# Stumped trying to set default audio device on ubuntu 22.10 with pipewire

Tags: sound, pipewire

Ubuntu 22.10 running Cinnamon or Plasma (X11)

I use USB speakers for audio ( Altec Lansing BXR1200's)   After every logout / reboot / sleep my audio output device gets reset to "Dummy Output" even though right next to it is "Speakers USB Audio".

If i goto the sound menu I can see "Speakers USB Audio" as an option and I have to manually select it every login / bootup.

I try to use a startup command 'pactl set-default-sink' with my device but it doesn't work, until I click on "Speakers USB Audio" on the sound device settings and when I do, "Dummy Audio" disappears.

Then the command finally works:

'pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.HiFihw_ALC1220VBDTsink'

I'm so confused as how to make that command work at bootup, or just circumvent the "Dummy Output"

Screenshot of the Dummy Output next to my Speakers.   As soon as I click my Speakers USB Audio the Dummy disappears and then I can use pactl set-default-sink, but it gets frustrating with every login and boot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iNzE.jpg